# Ordering two reference arrays together

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose

Suppose I have the following schemas:

```
var QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
    questionGroups: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'QuestionGroup' }]
});

var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true }, // e.g. 1, a, i, anything
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, enum: ['multiple choice', 'multiple select', 'short answer'] },
    choices: [String],
    answers: [String]
});

var QuestionGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true }, // e.g. 1, a, i, anything
    prompt: { type: String },
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]
});
```

I am trying to **design a way that will allow me to order questions and question groups together**.

I was thinking maybe of adding a new field `order`

```
var QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    order: [
        {
            type: { type: String, enum: ['Question', 'QuestionGroup'] },
            id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId // reference
        }
    ]
});
```

such that in the database, the field would contain something such as

```
[
     { type: 'Question', id: ObjectId('57867a34567g67790') },
     { type: 'Question', id: ObjectId('57867a34567g67765') },
     { type: 'QuestionGroup', id: ObjectId('69864b64765y45645') },
     { type: 'Question', id: ObjectId('57867a34567g67770') },
     { type: 'QuestionGroup', id: ObjectId('69864b64767y45647') }
]
```

This may mean that I would need to "populate" the ordered list of questions and question groups as

```
quiz.populate('questions questionGroups').exec(function (err, quiz) {
    // sort questions and groups by the order
    quiz.order = quiz.order.map(function (o) {
        if (o.type === 'QuestionGroup') {
            return quiz.questionGroups.id(o.id);
        }
        return quiz.questions.id(o.id);
    });
});
```

So my question: is there a better way to design this?

Comment: Essentially you want questions and questionGroups in an array one after another, when you find quiz?

Comment: @TalhaAwan That's about right. Their order may change though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html) can come in handy here; without persisting `order` field in db and doing calculations on client each time:

```
var QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
    questionGroups: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'QuestionGroup' }]
},
{
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true 
    }
}
);

QuizSchema
.virtual('order')
.get(function() {
    return this.questions.concat(this.questionGroups); //questions followed by questionGroups
});
```

Sort on `createdAt` is of course optional, but for that you need to have this field in Question and QuestionGroup:

```
Quiz.find({}, function (err, quiz) {
    //...
})
.populate({path : 'questions', options: {sort: { 'createdAt': 1 }}})
.populate({path : 'questionGroups', options: {sort: { 'createdAt': 1 }}});
```